# fetch dependencies while install deb with ansible

Tags: debian, mysql, ansible

i'm trying to install mysql 8.0.15-1debian9 on a debian 9 server

the problem is that mysql only provides the latest version of mysql in their apt repository which is 8.0.16-1debian9

however 8.0.16-1debian9 is still available in their apt repo

i'm trying to install it with the following task ( mysql official repo is also installed)

```
- name: Install MySQL 8.0.15 Community Server
  apt:
    deb: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/pool/mysql-8.0/m/mysql-community/mysql-community-server_8.0.15-1debian9_amd64.deb
```

which fails with this error

```
  msg: |-
    Dependency is not satisfiable: mysql-client (= 8.0.15-1debian9)
```

is there any clear work around for this ?

i want to avoid shell and command module as much as possible .

Comment: This may help https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Rosetta

Comment: Are you able to install it from the command line? Why do you think it is Ansible problem?

Comment: @Biswapriyo i couldn't find any specific command to use

Comment: @VladimirBotka no i couldn't install it from command line . it's not a Ansible problem at all , i just want to do it via Ansible

Comment: @shalbafzadeh Ansible can't help you if you are not able to configure it from the command line. Very probably you need to fix the repositories. Try from the command line first and then proceed with [apt_repository](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/apt_repository_module.html#apt-repository-module) and [apt](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/apt_module.html#apt-manages-apt-packages).

Answer (score 1):

As we can use apt, this way:

```
apt-get install mysql=8.0.15-1debian9
```

We may able to use the ansible apt module the same way:

```
apt: name=mysql=8.0.15-1debian9 state=installed
```

Comment: it doesn't work :( https://pastebin.com/N2N0v4fd